# Syncfusion Sample Model Error Message: Index and length must refer to a location within the string

Tags: syncfusion, codefluent

When building the Model from the Syncfusion sample, downloaded from Github, I get the following error:

> Index and length must refer to a location within the string

https://github.com/SoftFluent/CodeFluent-Entities/tree/master/Samples/SoftFluent.Samples.Syncfusion

I did install the pre-requisites including the WPF components from http://www.syncfusion.com/products/wpf

**Additional Information Added After Initial Post of Question**

I isolated the error to the Syncfusion WPF producer. When I disable the producer the error goes away. I tried re-compiling ContactManager.SyncfusionProducer.dll and placing it in C:\Program Files (x86)\SoftFluent\CodeFluent\Modeler. I got the same error.

Comment: I do not reproduce the error. May you please include the full stack trace (you can get it from the output window).

Answer (score 0):

The reported issue : **Index and length must refer to a location within the string**

This type of issue occurs when you try to extract the part of the data which is less than its index or out of index.
I have checked and not able to reproduce the reported issue. It would be helpful to resolve your issue, by providing the code snippet that you have tried in your application and also the stacktrace of exception that you have faced.